# How to do a Secure Authorization with RSA, AES and JWT?

Tags: security, encryption, jwt, aes, rsa

First of all, let me explain u what i imagin to do:

Lets Imagin Bob want to get Authorizat by Alice (Classic Example), in my Example Alice is a Server.

Lets Imagin too that Bob and Alice already got each RSA Key (4096).

So Bobs Steps to do that would be:

1. Sign credits (Plaintext) with SHA512 and his private Key
2. Encrypt Signed Data and Credits with AES CBC 256
3. Encrypt AES Key with RSA
4. Sending Datas to Alice

So Alice would do the steps abouve from the opposite to decrypt it and verify its from Bob.

After Alice verify that its Bob, she generate a JWT Token and Sign this with her Private Key and Return it in the Response Header Authorization.

The JWT got a TTL from 3600.

So far so good but my Question is now how do we Protect the JWT from getting Stoled ?

Sure its Signed so its cannot be Modified (Except Attacker got Private Key from Server but my god then its anyways over).

Lets Imagin he would be Able to Break the HTTPS and stealing the token, put it in his Header and so he can Trick Alice to believe him untill its Expire and he need to send the Credits again.

I was thinking about two Options:

Option 1:
Always sending Credits and Decrypted to verify Bob.

But this would be costing Huge Perfomance each time of request and the benefits from JWT gets lost.

Option 2: 
Sending a Unique ID and confirm its from Bobs Device (Encrypted, so same Problem like Option 1)

What could we do to protect that?

Maybe im Overthink to much, like always, but i would really like to know what in that case would be a "Best Practise".

Thank u already for ur Answers

Comment: try to send a timestamp with the signature

Comment: @Makdous thank u i Edit my Question. Forgot to point the TTL out sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far so good but my Question is now how do we Protect the JWT from getting Stoled ?

As you already found out, it's https

> Lets Imagin he would be Able to Break the HTTPS and stealing the token

If someone is able to break HTTPS then we have a much bigger issue then a stolen header.  By default you could trust https (except special cases in some countries)

Let's assume the channel is not secure, you may  for example sign every message separately (with an unsecure channel it's not enough to secure just a header).

Comment: Ur right its would be a huge misstake if the HTTPS breaks. For that i used the Example where the content would be Encrypted Seperatly. And sure if the PK of Alice would get stolen then its over bec u would be able to sign always the JWT by ur own and Alice would belive it. And sure nothing is secure in this world i was just wondering if its giving a good way to deal with that JWT

Answer (score 0):

Well, If Alice is not sure of who is sending the request then so is Bob, So its a two-way problem, **No one** is certain of the other's identity, You can fix that with a singed certificate from a certificate authority.
Where you send with the signature a certificate, And this certificate is singed with the private key of the certificate authority (a third party), Which insures that the connection between the client server is secure and prevents any modification.

Comment: Well but its got nothing to do when someone was able to steal the header ? I mean sure a certificate from e.g GoDaddy is anyways better and to use HTTPS anyways. But i mean if that fails then someone can not readying the Content bec its Encrypted but he can get the Header and fake with that the Identity.

Comment: let's say he stole the header,he then would have to modify the timestamp to make it acceptable to the receiver, Which means he has to change the signature that got sent with header,and that will make invalid because its singed with the private key, And lastly the certificate which will make sure that nothing is modified or changed in either the signature or the decrypted header, So i find the scenario where someone steal the header and be able to reuse it almost impossible.

Comment: Im totally agree with that point. Sure he can not Modify it but he can still use it for the time as long its valid. Maybe i didnt point it out good for each next request Alice would belive its Bob or i have fail in my thinking way ?

Comment: Just keep in mind that the _Middle Man_ can't get the header alone if its encapsulated in all those security layers.

Comment: Well thats true but as i sayed in my post, i may overthinking a bit in this points but thanks u anyways for ur answers mate =)